# Cocoa: Remove Database on uninstallation from OS X

Tags: database, xcode, macos, sqlite, xcode6.1

My COCOA OS X project has sqlite database which is stored in Application support Directory, So how to remove Database file on uninstallation of project from os x

Comment: Write an uninstaller ?